# Should I use Java EE 6 or stick with version 5 for the Java Pet Store app?

Tags: java, debugging, web-applications, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy the java Pet Store sample App, and it's documentation says that:

```
Java Pet Store 2.0 is the reference application for building AJAX
web applications on Java EE 5.
```

So does that mean it might not be compatible with the newer Java EE 6?

Comment: If you're taking the time to upgrade, have you considered Java 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java world, backwards compatibility is **very** important. Java EE 5 applications are definitely backwards compatible with Java EE 6. I.e., they can perfectly run on a Java EE 6 container.

It only means that it's designed and developed for Java EE 5 and does not utilize all available Java EE 6 features, like as the new builtin and Ajax-enabled MVC framework JSF 2.0. It also basically means that you're viewing and playing with an outdated demo application and that the demo is not necessarily built using latest best practices. Java EE 5 is over 5 years old already.

Comment: Thank You So Much for this thorough answer.